# How to show all plugins from Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript

I am having some troubles on listing the plugins from IE plugins using Javascript like Panopticlick does.
I am using the `plugin.name` but it does not run on IE

[image]

Any suggestions or used code examples? Thank you

Comment: http://www.ifadey.com/2011/09/browser-plugin-detection/

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.plugins` will work for IE 11 but not for earlier IEs. More on IE and plugins can be read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn423948(v=vs.85).aspx). For earlier IEs, you will need to check for each plugin manually by trying:

```
try {
   new ActiveXObject('aPluginName');
   return true;
} catch(e) {
   return false;
}
```

Main problem is, that plugins in IE are ActiveX based, which means each has its own API and there is no way you can check this in a general "catch-them-all" way. I found [this link quite helpful.](http://www.matthewratzloff.com/blog/2007/06/26/detecting-plugins-in-internet-explorer-and-a-few-hints-for-all-the-others/)